# multiple heroku apps, different endpoints, not subdomains

Tags: python, heroku, playframework, subdomain, flask

I have a heroku app using python and flask.  It currently serves a whole domain and all endpoints.

- http://*.domain.com/* -> one heroku app

I like to explore different languages and frameworks, and want to rewrite different sections of the website.  Is that possible?

It would work out to something like

- http://www.domain.com/python-stuff (a python/flask app)
- http://www.domain.com/ruby-stuff (a ruby/sinatra app)
- http://www.domain.com/java-play-stuff (a java/playframework app)

All I can see is possibly having one app that handles www and all subdirs, and redirects to a different subdomain instead.

- http://www.domain.com/ruby-stuff -> http://ruby-stuff.domain.com/ruby-stuff
- http://www.domain.com/java-play-stuff -> http://java-play-stuff.domain.com/java-play-stuff
- http://www.domain.com/{{ everything else }} -> the original python flask app

I don't want to do this because then I'd have to restructure all of my openid users to point to www.domain.com for their seed url explicitly instead of relying that all logins are coming from the same subdomain.  (Among other reasons like cookies (well that's related to open id also)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Setup an Amazon CloudFront distribution and have it map specific paths to different origin servers.